# Top tips for multithreading (Windows platform)

Tags: windows, multithreading

What are the tips you would offer to somebody who is developing a multithreaded application?

The only ones I can think of are:

- Where it is avoidable, do not have multiple threads writing to the same data structure.
- Where this cannot be avoided, have critical sections so that the latecoming thread will wait until is complete.
- Avoid having global variables except constants.
- Make sure that threads release the resource as soon as they are finished with them.

Can anybody think of anything else?

Comment: This might make an interesting community wiki article.

Comment: It's Too vague for that. And everything he's said so far is generic, not specific to Windows.

Comment: This is far to vague to be an actual question. For open-ended questions wiki would be appropriate.

Comment: I agree with the others... at least give us a language you plan to work in.

Comment: I like your question. I've dealt with multithreading on about a dozen different platforms now, and the issues on each are very similar. I think the more general question has merit. I've tried to provide a moderately general answer with some Visual Studio tips thrown in.

Answer (score 2):

Given the breadth (or ambiguity) of the question, I suggest you pick up a copy of Concurrent Programming on Windows by Joe Duffy, ISBN: 978-0-321-43482-1

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading is a very complex issue - my biggest advice would be to:

1. Consider if there are any alternatives - often the complexity of multithreading is underestimated.
2. If you're new to multithreading, start out small and keep things simple - take the time to really understand **exactly** how your threads are interacting with each other - what threads will be doing the same things at the same time, and what threads will be waiting on each other.

That said, I honestly believe that there is nothing fundamentally difficult about multithreading, it's just that a lot of programmers are so used to single-threaded programming that they make assumptions that aren't valid in multithreaded environments. If you're new to multithreading then you should approach it with extreme care for this reason, however you do get used to it with time.

Comment: I've got mixed feelings about your item 1... I agree that it's common for people to assume multithreading is the answer when there are performance issues causing the assumption that multithreading is needed--but multithreading is a core concept.  Things as small as "I can't click the cancel button!" to "if our server gets x messages it starts ignoring some" are common symptoms caused by a lack of thought put into the necessity of multithreading.  It's just another case of needing to know when and when not to

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with and developing multithreaded applications for years. It always amazes me how long a topic can take until I believe I have some mastery over it. This year will be the year of multi-threading for me.

Here are my multi-threading tips:

1. Don't write multi-threaded applications. When possible, just stay away from it. Way back in the days of COM, you had to choose your threading model for the object, and in almost all cases it was better to give each thread all its own memory and objects to deal with. Nothing has changed. Multi-threaded applications are an order of complexity harder than single threaded applications. They are just as hard and confusing as they were in 1995. All the high level objects which assist with multithreading cannot shield you from the increase in logical complexity that you invite.
2. Isolate your shared objects. If you have to write multi-threaded apps, understand that the only big challenge with multithreading is concurrent updates to the same object. There are other small issues, but that is the big one.
3. Imagine friendly threads executing around you. If you are in an UpdatePerformers function on a web server and you are coding:
       If (!List.Contains(performer))
           { List.Add(performer)}

   ```
   a. Imagine another thread executing on exactly the same line.
   b. On the line before or after
   c. Entering the function
   ```
4. Imagine friendly threads modifying non-local objects as you access them.
5. Lock the parent. If there is a logical parent which gets modified in complex ways, the simplest way to serialize access is to lock the parent object.
       a. If you have an order which contains order items and quantities and options, then lock the whole Order object when you modify any aspect.
       b. If you have a game with rounds and round details, lock the individual game when you modify the game or children.
6. After you acquire your lock, check to see if you still need to do anything.

   ```
   If (!Game.IsFinalized){
      Lock(Game) { 
           If (!Game.IsFinalized) 
           FinalizeGame(Game)}
   ```

   a. On the line after the lock is acquired, test the game again for IsFinalized, because it is OFTEN locked because another thread has acquired the lock to do exactly the same thing.

   b. Or, if it is your convention to do so, check in the Called Function to see if Game.IsFinalized before doing work. Just make sure to check.
7. Assume nothing is threadsafe! Thread safety is often at the expense of performance, or it often defines limitations to the functionality of an object or unnecessary complexity… so most objects are NOT threadsafe. Don't think, "But I'm using the latest, greatest framework!" It's not threadsafe. Entity Framework is not threadsafe.
8. ConcurrentCollections are great in .NET. You'll notice there's no "List" in the namespace. ConcurrentLists are more tricky because randomized inserts into a multi-threaded numbered list are fuzzy and/or impossible. Stacks, Queues, Bags and Dictionaries are usually fine. Plan accordingly.
9. On long iterations, make a copy of the list before you iterate through it. If your collection is being modified while you're iterating through it, it's probably an error in your logic… but sometimes it's just best to lock a list, create a shallow copy (ToList()) and iterate over that.
10. In .NET, Task objects are worth checking out. They're great for queuing serial work. Locks are generally fine and can be pretty simple and compact.
11. If you have no resource acquisition delays in your program, your number of threads should try to match the number of processors. If you have a four core machine, the only reason to run more than four threads in an application is when the scenario requires a thread to go into a wait state while acquiring resources. Thread context switches are expensive.
12. Threads are moderately expensive to create. If you're spinning them up on demand and destroying them often, the overhead can be considerable. Use a thread pool.
13. Don't accidentally lock on a non-static object. I've made this mistake a few times: private Object _lockGameUpdate on a web service. A new copy of the web service object is used for each call, so lock(_lockGameUpdate) in the file effectively does nothing. Since you often use lock variables only to lock, it's easy to mis-scope them. private STATIC Object _lockGameUpdate, of course, works as expected.
14. During testing, test:
        a. A bunch of threads starting at the same time
        b. Staggered creation of threads
        c. Double calling from separate threads with the exact same parameters.
15. Don't multithread. There's usually a better option.

Visual Studio

You can control whether a breakpoint suspends all threads or only the breaking thread. In a conditional breakpoint, you can put Thread={ThreadId} to make sure other threads you aren't debugging aren't smacking into your breakpoints.

You can freeze another thread. Do it in the threads window. It is often useful to "select all threads" (ctrl-a), then deselect the thread you want to debug, and click "Freeze Thread" to isolate your debugging.

Name your threads. The name you give them shows up in the thread window.

Good logging can be crucial. Multithreading plays havoc with the debugger, especially when evaluating variables.

Just an added note. The issues we deal with in database row and table locking are exactly the evolution we've progressed along for multi-threading resource sharing/locking. All the ideas like pessimistic and optimistic locking and how the database works internally to transact, if understood well... is a form of multithreading mastery in and of itself. All the ideas and performance tradeoffs you find with the decisions in SQL Server locking and concurrency are just multithreading in a different domain.

The difficulty in multithreading is NOT framework or syntax based. It is LOGIC based, so any of the concurrency solving systems like databases are forced to solve the exact same LOGICAL problems. Think about it that way if you have such an experience to draw on.

Answer (score 0):

If locking several objects, try to always lock them in the same order.  This should minimize your exposure to deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Basic advice:
**Design and planning**
-spend some time understanding exactly what should be executed, identify priorities and what can be done in asynchronous mode
**Resource control**
-use an efficient method to control shared resources, critical section is a good method for this
**Avoid recreating threads**
-reuse of threads brings efficiency and performance
**Prioritize activities**
-log recording must be made ​​by a specific thread for this purpose, so the core does not waste time

Answer (score -1):

Use row-level locking.

Use the TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED isolation level.

Avoid queries that cannot use indexes; they require locking of all the rows in the table (if only very briefly) and might block an update.

[Multithreading: Programming Tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e.aspx)